# Intent-filter for service start

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, intentfilter

I want to start a service, the service is basically a videoview on windowmanager. I want to start this videoview service even from other applications. 
this is my code intent-filter, Don't know where I went wrong.

```
  <service android:name=".VideoWindow">
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="video/*"  />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-quicktimeplayer*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-mpeg" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.dvd*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.3gp*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/3gpp*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.rn-realmedia*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/mp4*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/mpeg*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message"/>
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: so you mean **activity**, and not **service**?

Comment: I want to start `service` from another application. That's why I used intents t recieve data from other apps to my app. the service is view on `windowmanager` floating on all apps.

Comment: and how do "other apps" would start your service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to start this videoview service even from other applications

Unless you are the one writing those other applications, or you hire people to write those other applications, no other applications will start your service.

My guess, from your `<intent-filter>`, is that you think that if another app calls `startActivity()` on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, that this will start your service. This is incorrect. `startActivity()` starts an activity. It will not start a service, no matter what `<intent-filter>` that service has.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Yeah I thought of doing that way. But there is no way that i can start service?

Comment: @Naroju: You can force other developers at gunpoint to change their apps to call `startService()`. Or, you can change your app to have a `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` activity have your `<intent-filter>`, and have it delegate the work to the service.

Comment: Yeah. thats what I did. I made a transparent activity with no layout which start service and kill activity after service starts.